# Large letter in align environment

Tags: align, fontsize, math-operators

I have the following formula in an align environment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\hspace*{5mm}w_{c} = \large{\textit{f}} _{w,c} * \frac{log(|C|)}{\int _{w,C}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

But I want that function sign *f* to be much larger. I can do this with \mathcal, but I cannot manage it with ordinary letters.

Comment: Unrelated: the log should be coded `\log`.

Comment: Exactly why? It seems very strange

Comment: @daleif Perhaps it's some kind of operator.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes then they are looking for a marked integral symbol (there are several of these) not an `f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the size specification *inside* the `\textit`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\hspace*{5mm}w_{c} = {\textit{\LARGE f}} _{w,c} * \frac{\log(|C|)}{\int _{w,C}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]